# How are signal processing techniques like wave-shaping applied to complex waves for which we do not know the equation?

Tags: signal-processing, wave-equation

I must prefix this by saying I am not entirely sure whether Mathematics is the best place for this, but as I am curious about the mathematical process behind this, I chose to post this here.

In waveshaping, a transfer function is applied to an input function. But, in most cases, we do not know the equation for the transfer function if it is one that has been hand drawn in i. e. the graph of the transfer function is drawn into the waveshaper.

Anyway, my question would be: mathematically, how do computers perform processing that necessitates knowledge of the equation of such functions?

Comment: Why do they have to have an equation? Couldn't knowing the value of the equation at set of points be enough?

Comment: Well, I understand waveshaping to work like so: an input function $a(t)$ is fed into a transfer function $f(x)$ to get the output $f(a(t))$. We may just use the values of $a(t)$ at each point, but we still need the form of the function $f(x)$ if we are to obtain $f(a(t))$.

Comment: As far as I am aware, the term "transfer function" implies convolution and not composition. Even so, if $f(t)$ is bandlimited and sampled at a high enough rate, there is no need for an analytic expression for it.

Comment: I'll have to read into that. Thanks!